# Implement Java methods in C# using IKVM

Tags: java, c#, ikvm

I have a jar file that has many unimplemented methods that returns null. This file will use as a java library to write java applications, As a API.
This applications will launch in my C# application using IKVM.
Everytime application executes the unimplemented methods, I get a NullReferenceException, I want to implement this methods in C# but I don't know how.
A thing like this:

```
// Java Code:
public static Displayable getDisplay(MIDlet m) { return null; }

// C# Code
[BindToJava("javax.microedition.lcdui.Display.getDisplay")]
public static Displayable GetDisplay(MIDlet m) { /*some c# code*/ }
```

Comment: Is there anyone?

Comment: In a easier way, I want to write definitions and classes in Java and method implementations in C#.